# What was typical of Ireland England court system in the 1700’s?

Tags: england, law, 18th-century, ireland, finance

In the 1700’s there were Court proceedings called ExChequer Court of Equity Bill Books ([e.g](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/62071/)) in Ireland. I found records of one of my ancestors in the early 1700’s who was a defendant several times owing money to some of his friends or family at different times, then he was a plaintiff on other occasions where different people owed him money. Most of them were related or were in-laws. I was wondering if this was standard practice back then where they used each other for loans instead of banks, but I wonder what all the issues could be to cause them to be there. Was it a dispute over them wanting more time to pay it back or the interest was too high, etc? This particular ancestor was from somewhat of a noble family.

Comment: Can you share any of the details of these court proceedings?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Legal systems can be weird.  There have been times when people went to court over a sale so there would a legal record.  Suing over a debt might work if they "settled."  Did they actually go to court?

Comment: Thank you for comments… I wanted to copy and paste images of the documents but I couldn’t figure out how to do that.

Comment: Each document will have a man’s name as Plaintiff then the defendants could be several people including their wives but there is no money amount listed or a subject as to what it was for.